# multiline text box to 2d array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, .net-4.0

How would I go about inserting the following input in to a 2d array or if required for the same effect a different kind of array.

```
  abcd
  efgh
  ijkl
```

and when I click a button my array rotates 90 degrees to the right or left (if chosen) I've been thinking about it for about an hour I tried a few things but I'm totally new at VB.net

example using numbers instead:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

rotated:

```
7 4 1
8 5 2
9 6 3
```

and so on

Comment: Could you explain what is a rotating array?

Comment: @Steve done, put example in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started You would want to dynamically set the upper bounds for the "rows" and "columns". This outputs it to a text box, but it would be easy enough to assign the variable to a new array.

```
Dim arr(3, 3) As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For row As Integer = 0 To 2
        For col As Integer = 0 To 2
            arr(row, col) = i
            i += 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub showStraight()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    For row As Integer = 0 To 2
        Dim line As String = ""
        For col As Integer = 0 To 2
            line += arr(row, col)
        Next
        TextBox1.Text += line & vbNewLine
        line = ""
    Next
End Sub    Public Sub showRotated()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    For col As Integer = 0 To 2
        Dim line As String = ""
        For row As Integer = 2 To 0 Step -1
            line += arr(row, col)
        Next
        TextBox1.Text += line & vbNewLine
        line = ""
    Next
End Sub
```